# UL next to each other inside a div

Tags: css

Hey there I need to help with `li`'s. I create this html code:

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dorem</li>
    <li>Lerum</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

And this CSS:

```
#menu ul {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```

I don't know why but it doesn't stacks next to each other. There is no CSS inside a #menu but in Chrome I noticed that it automatically added this to CSS `display: block;`. May it be a problem?

Comment: Change you CSS to `#menu ul li {...}` instead.

Comment: Made a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/7qMKn/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have to put inline each `li`:

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/LrSyS/

```
<div id="menu">
  <ul>
    <li>Lorem</li>
    <li>Ipsum</li>
    <li>Dorem</li>
    <li>Lerum</li>
  </ul>
</div>

#menu li {
   display: inline;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
#menu ul li{
    display: inline;
    list-style-type:none;
}
```